# Distinct single item in foreach loop

Tags: php, css, loops

In my code i get a bunch of results from my database like so:

```
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT sm.taak,u.username FROM schedule_mon AS sm JOIN users AS u ON sm.user_id=u.id');
$records->execute();
$results = $records -> fetchAll();
```

Then i loop through the results like this:

```
foreach( $results as $row ) {
echo $row['taak']." ".$row['username']."</br>";
}
```

My results look like this:

```
Tafel dekken Peter
Tafel afruimen Chrisformer
Afwasmachine inruimen Frek
Afwasmachine uitruimen desley
```

The format is basically a task and then the user that has to perform that task. I would now like to know, lets say the user that has to perform a task is named Peter. How do i give peter a different color than the others.

So if user = peter then put peter in an `<li>` with a certain class. So i can give it a distinct color in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<span>` around the part you want to color differently:

```
foreach( $results as $row ) {
  if ($row['username'] == "Peter") {
    echo $row['taak']." <span class='className'>".$row['username']."</span></br>";
  } else {
    echo $row['taak']." ".$row['username']."</br>";
  }
}
```

Than use CSS to assign a color to the className:

```
.className {
  color:red;
}
```